# cordova app with jquery, php

Tags: php, jquery, cordova

I'm trying to make a hybrid app using cordova and I want to ask two questions?
One of them is the login, I did it with jquery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $("#submit_btn").on("click", function(){
        var username = $("#username").val();
        var pass = $("#pass").val();

        $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "link",
                data: { username: username},
                sucess: function () {
                }
               })  
        });
    });
</script>
```

Is this a "right" way to do it?
and the best way to connect to a database?

```
<?php

header('Acess-Controll-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Acess-Controll-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PATCH, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS');

if(isset($_POST)) {
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $pass = $_POST['pass'];
    require("connect.php");

    $sql = "INSERT INTO fields VALUES ('$username'. '$pass')";
    mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql);
}

?>
```

I'm getting this error:
Notice: Undefined index: $username in /home/wm29tzgj/public_html/areacliente/insert.php on line 7

Notice: Undefined index: $pass in /home/wm29tzgj/public_html/areacliente/insert.php on line 8

```
<div class="signin-form">

        <div class="container">


           <form class="form-signin" method="post" id="login-form">

            <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Log In to WebApp.</h2><hr />

            <div id="error">
            <!-- error will be shown here ! -->
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
            <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" name="username" id="username" />
            <span id="check-e"></span>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
            <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" name="password" id="password" />
            </div>

          <hr />

            <div class="form-group">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" name="btn-login" id="btn-login">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> &nbsp; Sign In
       </button> 
            </div>  

          </form>

        </div>

    </div>
```

Comment: For that you need to call server side script file like php,asp etc.In that file you can write to connect with database.

Comment: yes I have a insert.php, but it's not working, I will update the post to show the php code

Comment: please check my answer and can you put html here?

Comment: @Jinesh I tried but the button was not doing nothing, I don't know what's wrong
I'm updating the post

Comment: You are inserting values into your database that leave you vulnerable to SQL Injection. Use the [execute function](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.execute.php) instead of mysqli_query to safely insert data.

Comment: first change button type submit to button like this <button type="button" id="submit_btn">

Answer (score 0):

Like this :

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {

            $("#submit_btn").on("click", function(){
            var username = $("#username").val();
            var pass = $("#password").val();

    $.ajax({
                   type: "POST",
                   url: "http://website.php",
                   data: {'username': username,"pass":pass },
                   cache: false,   
                   success: function (data) { 
                    }              
                 });
      });
    </script>
```

Comment: can you check the insert.php too please?

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 var username="";
 var passTxt="";
        $(document).ready(function () {

            $("#submit_btn").on("click", function(){
            username = $("#username").val();
             passTxt = $("#password").val();

    $.ajax({
                   type: "POST",
                   url: "http://website.php",
                   data: {'username': username,"pass":passTxt },
                   cache: false,   
                   success: function (data) { 
                    }              
                 });
      });
    </script>
```